# Extract files from a Norton Ghost archive

Tags: extract, norton-ghost

How to extract files from a Norton Ghost archive... without Norton Ghost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a compressed drive image, you'll need Ghost Explorer (Ghostexp.exe) for that.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can do this without Norton Ghost. BUT you can do this without installing Norton Ghost on your computer. If you have a Ghost 9 CD, you can extract "PQIBrowser.exe" and "PQIBrowser.exe.manifest" from the setup package. When you run this program, it will let you browse the contents of a drive image and even copy files out.

Hope that helps.

PS: for Ghost 15, the file is called v2iBrowser.exe